# Сортировка словаря по значениям в порядке убывания

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, словарь

Есть словарь с городами и их населением, никак не получается отсортировать по убыванию.

```
city = {
    "Kiyv":("2884000"),
    "Odessa":("993120"),
    "Tokyo":("9071577"),
    "Mexico City":("8874724"),
    "London":("8416500"),
    "Bogota":("7776845"),
    "Singapore":("5399200"),
    "Hong Kong":("7219700"),
    "Ankara":("5150072"),
    "Istanbul":("14377019"),
    "Lahore":("11318745"),
    "New York City":("8491079"),
    "Nanjing":("8187828"),
    "Rio de Janeiro":("6429923"),
    "Pune":("5049968"),
    "Tehran":("8154051"),
    "Abidjan":("4765000")
}

v = list(city.values())
v.sort#на выходе получается первый "Lahore", а должен "Istanbul"
k = list(city.items())
for i in v:
    for j in range(len(k)):
        if(i in k[j]):
            print(k[j])
```

Comment: вы к врачу тоже приходите и сидите, молча смотря на него?

Comment: числовые строки сортируем?

Comment: да, чтобы вывело город и его население от большего к меньшему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(*sorted(city.items(), key = lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse = True), sep = "\n")
```